# Connect to mysql from nodeJS with NO dependencies at all

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, protocols

I've seen various questions on here as well as the npm library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Which is even recommended by w3schools, but i haven't been able to find any information on making a mysql client from just plain native nodejs (using the .net module only if needed)

In aware that mysql doesn't communicate by means of http requests, but rather some other kind of socket, i haven't been able to find the specifications for this protocol, nor any tutorials that explain how to implement it with nodejs

Comment: Did you look at the source code to the mysql lib you mentioned?

Comment: I think covering [the entire MySQL protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_PROTOCOL.html) is a bit out of scope for SO.

Comment: @hover no i have quite a bit of trouble reading other people's code and making sense of it

Comment: @vlaz just asking for a reference to a place that does cover it

Comment: @vlaz and perhaps some kind it tutorial

Comment: Asking for tutorials and other off-site resources is also off-topic for SO.

Comment: @vlaz k not JUST asking for tutorials, at least a minimal example or brief explanation followed by a direct reference would be nice, if someone has a question if how to push an element to an array is that too complicated since the entire structure of the Array class is beyond the scope of so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL Client/Server Protocol is documented here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html

That's the only resource I know of. I know it's out of date, but the concepts in it are a good introduction.

Frankly, every project that develops their own implementation of the MySQL protocol do so by reading the code. The code is by definition the most accurate and up to date representation of the protocol.

The changes to the MySQL protocol are incremental. What you learn from that documentation will help you understand the code.

This is not the kind of project that has a tutorial. The audience of potential readers is so small that it wouldn't be worth developing a tutorial.

I know of a few implementations of the MySQL protocol. For example:

- [libmysqlclient](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-implementations.html), which is the client library included in the MySQL source code. This is written in C.
- [PHP's mysqlnd extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), which is also written in C, but it's a separate implementation because it's licensed differently.
- [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/), which is a Java implementation of the client.
- [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), which is a Node.js implementation of the MySQL protocol in 100% javascript. This may be exactly what you propose to develop. But using it would technically be a dependency.

Frankly, I would just use one of the existing implementations. Developing a new implementation is bound to take months, even if you had strong understanding of the protocol already. It's meticulous work.

Comment: Says there `The content in this chapter is outdated. For current information, please refer to the Client/Server Protocol section of the MySQL Server Doxygen documentation, available at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html.` yet in not able to find the documentation on that page?